# Lines of all directions in the plane

Tags: measure-theory, plane-geometry

A line of slope $a$ is placed in the plane for every real number $a$ (these lines need not pass through the origin.) Does the set of points not on any of these lines have finite area?

I'm not sure if the phrasing in this problem is precisely correct, so please correct me if my meaning is unclear.

Obviously the area is not always $0$; for example, choosing all lines tangent to a given circle leaves the interior of the circle untouched.

Comment: Do you mean lines through the origin? There are many lines of slope $a$ in the plane; if you can choose any one of them for each slope, it's easy to place them such that they avoid any given bounded area. You need to say something about which lines of slope $a$ you mean.

Comment: No, the lines need not pass through the origin. I've edited for clarity - hopefully this helps.

Comment: But if you've already realized that you can make them tangent to a circle, why are you asking whether the set of points not on the lines has finite area? You get all the slopes along one half-circle, e.g. the upper one, and the entire infinite strip under the circle, which has infinite area, is left.

Comment: @joriki: That seems like a (fine) answer.

Comment: @quasi: OK. I was still in the mode of checking whether I'd understood the question properly, but then I'll post it.

Answer (score 2):

The lines can leave a zero, finite or infinite area uncovered. (I suspect they can also leave an unmeasurable set uncovered.)

If the lines go through the origin, the entire plane is covered.

If the lines are tangent to a semicircle, an infinite strip on the other side of the circle is left uncovered.

It's slightly less straightforward to leave a finite area uncovered, but it's possible. The lines

$$
\pmatrix{t\\0}+\lambda\pmatrix{\sin\frac t{1+t}\alpha\\\cos\frac t{1+t}\alpha}\;,
$$

where $\lambda$ is the line parameter and $t$ parametrizes the family of lines, only use the angle range $[0,\alpha]$, cover the entire first and second quadrants but leave the entire third quadrant uncovered. Three such families starting out at the edges of a triangle can be made to have non-overlapping angle ranges and to cover everything except for the triangle; the remaining slopes can then be “wasted” e.g. by making them tangent to the triangle's circumcircle.